# Does an algorithm depend on underlying number representation?

Tags: algorithm, binary

An algorithm in general, would use variables(example: max, min etc) to maintain the logical status, while solving a problem. A variable is represented by number in computer(hardware).

Computers are designed to use binary digits to represent numbers and other information. But, it is possible(or already been tried) to use a different number representation(example ternary, for what-ever may be the advantage, it does not matter).

Now, does the algorithm depend on this number representation by the underlying computer? i.e does an algorithm written on(and not "for") a computer X with number representation Nx work exactly same on a computer Y having number representation Ny?

Comment: " work exactly same": of course not, as the numeration system is different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun

Comment: Logically yes - meaning that given enough time, the algorithm will produce the same output no matter the substrate. However, different systems might have different efficiencies - maybe one is much faster at adding 1 to a number... and this would mean different algorithms could run faster or slower in real time, despite having the same big-O.

Comment: Hmm , Many financial algorithms have trouble with base 2 and work best with base 10  representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both available algorithms and their properties can depend on the representation.

As an example [How can I speed up the binary GCD algorithm using __builtin_ctz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604914/how-can-i-speed-up-the-binary-gcd-algorithm-using-builtin-ctz) is asking about how to implement an algorithm that very much depends on the binary representation of the number.

Secondly there are a lot of details that depend on the representation.  For example if you're working with floating point, you'll get roundoff errors that in finance can result in mismatched pennies.  By contrast if you were working with base 10 arithmetic, there would be no roundoff errors.

You wouldn't think that a penny matters.  But the first thing people do with a financial model is "verify that it ties out".  And I've seen people spend days tracking down a missing dime.

UPDATE: As noted in the comments, I initially said "No" and meant "Yes" in the first sentence.  So I switched it and added a clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the response; I understand the dependency in financial (and any such) application, where accuracy depend on the number representation. For the sake of argument, we can bundle all such properties of algorithm(which depend on number representation) into a logical module(say shared library) and then, use them according to the accuracy requirements. What I need to know is(as arbuthnott commented below the question), if we are not bothered about the speed(and the expected accuracy concerns), then there should no difference isn't it?

Comment: @GanapathiBhat If we choose not to care about all the things we actually care about, then we can arrange not to care about the differences.  That is trivially true and not very useful.